# What does the phrase "straightly charging that" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Sultan] Murad assured Elizabeth [I] he had commanded ‘all our kings, judges, and travellers by sea’ throughout the Ottoman Empire to ensure that ‘such aforesaid persons as shall resort thither by sea from the realm of England, either with great or small vessels to trade by way of merchandise, may lawfully come to our imperial dominions, and freely return home again . . . ***straightly charging** that they be suffered to use and trade all kind of merchandise as any other Christians do, without let or disturbance’.*

Jerry Brotton, *This Orient Isle- Elizabethan England and the Islamic World*

Comment: It means "Clearly ordering".  "Straightly" = "In a clear, uncomplicated style" and "to charge" here = "to command, instruct, or exhort with authority".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those Elizabethan times, *straightly* was used in the sense of *immediately*, *at once*, *hereafter*. *Straight* itself is still defined as *immediately* in dictionaries (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straight).

You will find *straightly* used in this sense in Shakespeare's plays. You may also find it in Elizabeth's own commands. For example in April 1559, she drafted a proposal that for the first time envisaged a system for the prior review and regulation of plays throughout her kingdom: *The Queen's Majesty doth straightly forbid all manner interludes to be played either openly or privately ...* Elsewhere, we may find *For Men's Apparell her Majestie doeth straightly charge and commaund that None shall wear in his Apparell Cloth of Gold ...*

One meaning of *to charge* is to *to order* (or command). Hence "straightly charging that ... " = "ordering that ... be done immediately ..." or "commanding that ... be done with immediate effect"

Answer (score 0):

This usage of '**straightly**' is found in the King James Version of the Bible:

> - Now Jericho was straightly shut up because of the children of Israel: none went out, and none came in. (Joshua 6:1)
> - And their eyes were opened; and Jesus straightly charged them, saying, See that no man know it. (Matthew 9:30)
> - Did not we straightly command you that you should not teach in this name? (Acts 5:28)

[[BibleHub AKJV](https://biblehub.com/joshua/6-1.htm) and similar] [American King James Bible; the British version has 'straitly']

The Joshua reference is translated 'securely', 'tightly' by other versions. The Acts reference has 'strictly', and most versions have 'strictly' or 'sternly' for the Matthew reference. The best interpretation here then ('immediately' doesn't work well) is '**strictly**', with overtones of '*explicitly*'.

To '**charge**' in this sense clearly means to 'order', 'command', as is easily looked up in almost any dictionary.